# API not being called on NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call a REST Api using NSUrlSession but it's not being called.

```
- (void)generateData {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Flying");
    }];
}
```

My NSLog is never printed and the internet on emulator is working because i'm using Auth0 to authenticate.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `resume` on your task in order to start it.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Flying");
}] resume];
```